# No exception of type UnderflowException can be thrown;

Tags: java, exception, throws, throwable

I am trying to implement a stack with some functions in Java. I have created the class UnderflowException that implements Exception like this:

```
package exceptions;

public class UnderflowException extends Exception
{
    public UnderflowException(String err)
    {
        super(err);
    }
}
```

When I'm implementing the Interface I get the following error
**"No exception of type UnderflowException can be thrown; an exception type must be a class of Throwable"** when I try to throw.

My interface looks like this:

```
import exceptions.*;
public interface Stack
{
    public void push(Object x);
    public void pop() throws UnderflowException;
    public Object top() throws UnderflowException;
    //other functions
}
```

Is there a problem with the UnderflowException class? Thank you!

Comment: Are you extending `java.lang.Exception` or some custom `Exception` class?

Comment: I believe it's `java.lang.Exception`.

Comment: That error message suggests that `Throwable` isn't in the type hierarchy of your `UnderflowException` class - which it definitely would be if you were extending `java.lang.Exception`. If there is a class called `Exception` in your exceptions package then you may be inadvertently inheriting from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Exception` with `java.lang.Exception`. Looks like you use wrong class and FQN help solve problem.

Comment: I've replaced `Exception` with `java.lang.Exception` and now seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: Look at your imports. Or maybe you have your own `Exception` class in this package. (Call you own class `Exception` is bad idea because it cause lots of misunderstandings)